# How to stop an image from overflowng in bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm trying to make a thumbnail icon inside of a jumbotron that has description and nothing works. Can you take a look please and tell me what I do wrong?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="jumbotron">
<h1 class="text-center">Kevin Mitnick</h1>
<h3 class="text-center">The World's Most Famous hacker</h3>
  <div class="thumbnail"><img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Nn3O8XD1z0w/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="Kevin's Picture">
    <div class="caption text-center"><p>Kevin Mitnick talking in the popular YouTube channel "Big Think".</p></div>
          </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
body {
  margin-top: 60px;
}
```

Comment: try adding a max-width / height to your image

Answer (score 0):

you have to resize your image or add width and height styles to your img Tag.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="jumbotron">
<h1 class="text-center">Kevin Mitnick</h1>
<h3 class="text-center">The World's Most Famous hacker</h3>
  <div class="thumbnail"><img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Nn3O8XD1z0w/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="Kevin's Picture">
    <div class="caption text-center"><p>Kevin Mitnick talking in the popular YouTube channel "Big Think".</p></div>
          </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I know about width and height. Since I'm using bootstrap I was the image to be resized automatically with a class or something.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has a class which applies this effect: `img-responsive`. This applies `max-width: 100%;`, `height: auto;` and `display: block;` to the image so that it scales nicely to the parent element.

In the upcoming Bootstrap 4 version this class was changed to `img-fluid`.

```
<img src="..." class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
```

More info can be found on [Bootstrap's site](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images) and the [Bootstrap 4 Alpha page](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/images/#responsive-images).

Comment: .img-responsive doesn't do anything to me. The image is still huge and overflowling.

Comment: I'm using this website to create the webpage: https://codepen.io/georgekech/pen/Lxqrvb I have bootstrap enabled. I don't know why it doesn't do it automatically.

Comment: @GeorgeKech I see the issue, you are using the alpha version of Bootsrap 4. In that version, the class is called `img-fluid`.

Comment: Yep. It solved the issue. But it still doesn't look like a thumbnail with it border and etc. And it doesn't have the description inside of it.

Comment: @GeorgeKech That is outside the scope of the question posed in the title but I assume it's because you need to change the wrapper element's class from `thumbnail` to `img-thumbnail`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly you don't want the image to overflow outside of it's parent element? In that case you can add an `overflow: hidden;` or for a responsive and scalable image use the class `img-responsive` to the image tag.